# Firebase realtime database rules are not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have the following firebase setup:

```
- root
  - v1
    - auth
     - "key1" : "value",
     - "key2" : "value,
     - ...
    - config
    - announcements
```

I want that everything should have `".write" :"auth!=null"`
And that everything is readable except for `auth` that should be `".read" : "auth!=null"`

I have tried the following rules but they don't work!

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth != null",
        "v1": {
            ".read": true,
            ".write": "auth != null",
            "auth": {
                ".read": "auth != null",
                ".write": "auth != null"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the data and code you are using to test this. Also how exactly don't these rules work? (Can you read when you shouldn't or vice versa?)

Comment: The auth node contains key - values pairs, when going to auth.json it actually shows me the data while it shouldn't

Comment: I thought so. You really need to add that kind of information in your question if you want people to help you. Simply saying something doesn't work is completely useless because that can mean a lot of things. But if you want something like this you are going to have to rewrite your rules differently because [rules cascade](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rules are giving everything in your database read access for everyone, but then trying to take away read access to some deeper child node.  You can't do this with Realtime Database rules.  Once you grant read access to a node, that node and all of its children are permanently readable.  In this case, database rules are said to "cascade".  You can't reject access to a child node if any of its parents are readable.

[Please read the documentation about cascading database rules.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade)

Comment: Thanks really helpfull